# Business card segmentation and location

Tags: opencv, edge-detection

Recently,I am writing a program for business card recognition. Firstly, we should segment the input image and locate the business card region. To do this I compute the gradient and then detect the lines using Hough transformation. In some cases this method works well, but in some cases it didn't because sometimes lines can be detected in the background. I don't know how to deal with this problem.
Please provide me some ideas and suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide some more information of the business card?  A picture might help people provide you with a better answer.

Comment: Do some foreground/background detection first then only work on the foreground

Comment: In the Opencv code there is an example application to detect rectangles in an image. This may be useful to you depending on the perspective you want to see the card from.

Comment: Try to detect rectangles:
http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/

http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/detecting-simple-shapes-in-an-image/

Comment: @GilLevi,my method also like [link](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/). But it didn't work well when some lines are detected in the background. When this happened I can't detect which one is the real edge of the card.

Comment: Yeah,I tried this method.But this method is not precise enough. @GPPK

Comment: Sorry,I'm a freshman in this website and have no reputation for uploading pictures. @maxf130 By the way thank you for your edit.

Comment: Try defining an ROI around your image using Rect class. That will eliminate the background